# How does the Roughness Curve work?

Tags: particles, hair

When you go into a particle setting and check Children -> Roughness -> Use Roughness Curve, you get the curve widget instead of roughness parameters:

[image: Roughness Curve]

In fact, that's pretty much all Blender's manual says about this feature:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/children.html#roughness

How does the Roughness Curve work? I've experimented a bit with the curve but am not seeing any obvious relationship between the curve and what I see on the rendered viewport.

Comment: This is a good question.  If you play with the hair children *Length* parameter with a high curve vs a low curve the result is interesting and perhaps somewhat informative.